# winsock и /NODEFAULTLIB

Tags: winapi, c, winsock, c++

При задании компоновщику ключа  */NODEFAULTLIB*  компилятор перестаёт видеть подключённую библиотеку winsock и я получаю lnk2001. Причём без этого параметра всё нормально, и winsock - единственная библиотека которая не хочет нормально работать. */NODEFAULTLIB* разве отключает что-то ещё кроме crt?

Answer (score 1):

*Что-то вы темните.*

`/NODEFAULTLIB` в тривиальном случае равносилен отключению линковки `msvcrt.lib` *(или соответствующей дебажной версии библиотеки)*. Таким образом, если руками прилинковать соответствующий рантайм, то ничего не изменится и на `wsock32.lib` это никак не должно влиять.

Только что проверил, собрав проект, активно использующий сокеты, с ключом `/NODEFAULTLIB`, вручную прилинковав `msvcrt.lib`.

Comment: В том то и проблема что влияет, из-за такой "магии" я и задал вопрос.
Попробовал по вашему примеру прилинковать crt - 0 эффекта.